# Find Mean, Standard Deviation and Variance of two co-ordinates

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I am doing a mini project and i am stuck with a code. My project is based Positioning.

I have used a GUI to get the original and estimated position of a target.

I have placed 8 nodes to test.

In this the first four are reference nodes and the next four are random position of the unknown nodes.

```
cors = [6.62650602409639 194.444444444445;
        6.62650602409639 10.6837606837607;
        192.168674698795 7.83475783475797;
        192.168674698795 191.595441595442;
        70.4819277108434 171.652421652422;
        129.518072289157 168.803418803419;
        24.6987951807229 144.586894586895;
        42.7710843373494 79.0598290598291];
```

I want to plot the graph between x and y co-ordinates.

I have used TOA to estimate the position of target and I got the following output.

```
cors_est = [6.62650602409639 194.444444444445;
            6.62650602409639 10.6837606837607;
            192.168674698795 7.83475783475797;
            192.168674698795 191.595441595442;
            70.7600705547484 171.847603055024;
            129.443055817301 168.734648868329;
            25.01956026761   144.890243978875;
            42.6058125534278 79.1446327727804];
```

From this, I have calculated the difference between `cors` and `cors_est`, let it be `le(x)` and `le(y)` where `le` is the localization error.

And with the data I have calculated `mean(x)= summation of le(x)/8;`

similarly,

```
mean(y)=le(y)/8;
ΔX = LE(X) − Mean(X)
ΔY = LE(Y) − Mean(Y)
```

Now i need some guidance in doing the following tasks :

1. To calculate the `stdx=square of (ΔX)` and `stdy=square of (ΔY)` and then,
2. `stdxy=summation of ((ΔX)+(ΔY))/N`

Actually if I take the square root of the above data, I will get the standard deviation.

Please guide me with this.

Waiting for some good guidance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this too hard.  How about:

```
meanXandY = mean(cors - cors_est, 1);
```

And

```
stdXandY = std(cors - cors_est, 0, 1);
```

Comment: +1 for the use of explicit dimensions. However, the syntax for [`std`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/std.html) is slightly different: use `std(cors - cors_est, 0, 1)` instead. The first `0` in there is to make it unbiased (i.e. divide by N - 1) and the `1` is to select the dimension.

Comment: You're right of course.  That's the danger of writing code without testing it.  I've made the change.

Comment: Thanks Pursuit.. It really helped me. But how about plotting a graph for original position and estimated position?

I want to plot a graph for cors and cors_est where both plots use different colors for differentiation.

Comment: @Pursuit: It's unlikely to notice the difference from the output, as it operates on the first non-singleton dimension, which happens to be the first one in this case. IMHO the syntax for `std` and `var` just begs for such small errors.

Comment: Now I am having two graphs. But the error is so small that i am unable to distinguish them. 


plot(cors(:,1),cors(:,2));

plot(cors_est(:,1),cors_est(:,2));

I want to use different colors for both plots in same figure so that i can analyze the result in graph.

Either we can increase the plot scale to be able to distinguish such minor differences and get the plots in different colors.

example : plotting the first plot(cors(:,1),cors(:,2)); in blue which is default and plotting the second one plot(cors_est(:,1),cors_est(:,2));
in red or green.

please guide me on this.